# Issue with url parameter calling WCF service from JQuery

Tags: wcf, web-services, jquery

I am trying to call the WCF service from Jquery. But if I replace the url with my machine name it doesn't work. The html/jquery and WCF are both on the same web site (project).  I think many people need help with this since there is no way to debug and figure out the problem. Instead of continuously changing the wcf service file, web.config file and html (ajax function) page, does anyone have a running project with this issue?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        //work well 
        //url: "Service1.svc/MyFunction",

        //work well
        //url: "http://localhost:43969/Service1.svc/MyFunction",

        //not work ???
        //url: "http://PWLL-IT-056:43969/Service1.svc/MyFunction",

        data: '{"Count": "' + counter + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
        success: ServiceSucceeded,
        error: ServiceFailed
    });
```

Thanks for help guys,

Comment: You can try to use Fiddler to see what is going wrong with your case.